# Shelf life of a Chocolate Product (incl. butter) - "Chocolate Salami"

Tags: food-safety, chocolate, storage-lifetime, sugar, butter

I have an old family recipe for something called a Chocolate Salami (don't worry, there isn't any meat) and I am wondering - if I vacuum seal it, will it be shelf stable?

I know the stability of butter and chocolate is exceptional but I'm wondering if anything changes when they are combined?

The recipe calls for the following: chocolate, butter, powdered sugar, crushed up crackers, and hazelnuts. The only cooking in the process is toasting the nuts and melting the chocolate/butter.

Thanks!

Comment: I imagine that this would freeze well, I would consider doing that.

Comment: I should mention that the end goal is larger scale production. Freezing will work for storage and transport, but may not be feasible for stores or consumers